# Selective custom parameters binding for complex types in ASP.NET WebAPI 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

All right, so after digging around SO and other resources I wasn't able to find a right solution for my requirements.

Let's say I have a complex type like this:

```
public class CreateItemRequest : AuthenticatedRequest
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuthenticatedRequest
{
    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller action for this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateItem(CreateItemRequest request)
{
   _aCoolInjectedBusinessLayer.CreateItem(request);
}
```

I need custom parameter binding only for property `AuthToken` from a custom header request. All other properties within inheritance should be populated by the default ASP.NET model binder.

If I use `IModelBinder` approach there's no way to selectively populate just some properties. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve what you need with custom implementation of `HttpParameterBinding`. It will be based on default implementation to perform all binding but will additionally check the custom header and fill `AuthToken` property. Here is working implementation:

```
public class AuthRequestBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private readonly HttpParameterDescriptor paramDescriptor;

    public AuthRequestBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor)
    {
        paramDescriptor = descriptor;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var defaultBinder = new FromBodyAttribute().GetBinding(paramDescriptor);
        await defaultBinder.ExecuteBindingAsync(metadataProvider, actionContext, cancellationToken);

        AuthenticatedRequest authRequest = actionContext.ActionArguments[paramDescriptor.ParameterName] as AuthenticatedRequest;
        if (authRequest != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Your-Custom-Header-Here", out headerValues))
            {
                authRequest.AuthToken = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register custom binder in Web API Config:

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, paramDesc =>
{
    if (typeof(AuthenticatedRequest).IsAssignableFrom(paramDesc.ParameterType))
    {
        return new AuthRequestBinding(paramDesc);
    }

    return null;
});
```